# Two PHP forms on same page

Tags: php, forms, captcha

I have two php forms on same page now the problem is I am calling them through an iframe but there captcha is not working though I am using the same script for both the forms with different input fields. Right now what happens is when we click first time on captcha and write correct captcha it take us to YOU HAVE ENTERED WRONG CAPTCHA and then we fill correct captcha then show us thanku...Why not it shows thanks for the first time when we enter correct captch??????

```
            <?php
            session_start();
            $tuCurl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
            $tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl); 
            curl_close($tuCurl); 
            $userip = explode(',',$tuData);
            $ipcountry = str_replace('"', '', $userip[3]);

            include "libmail.php";  
            $errors = '';
            //print_r($_POST);
            if(isset($_POST['email']))
            {
                if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) ||
                  strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['captcha']) != 0)
                {
                    $errors .= "You have entered wrong captcha code!";
                }elseif($_FILES["userfile"]["size"] > 1048576)
                {
                    $errors .= "You can upload maximum of 800kb file!";
                }else{

                        $productsq      = $_POST['productsq'];
                    $name       = $_POST['name'];
                    $position       = $_POST['position'];
                    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];

                    $company    = $_POST['company'];
                    $companyweb = $_POST['companyweb'];
                    $address    = $_POST['address'];
                    $country    = $_POST['country'];
                                    $brief      = $_POST['brief'];
                    $email      = $_POST['email'];


                    $captcha    = $_POST['captcha'];

                    $sender = $contact_email;

                    function clean_string($string) {
                      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
                    }

                    if(trim($productsq) !='')
                        $email_message .= "*I'm interested in  : ".clean_string($productsq)."\n"."\n";

                    if(trim($name) !='')
                        $email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n"."\n";

                                if(trim($position) !='')
                        $email_message .= "Position/Title: ".clean_string($position)."\n"."\n";

                                            if(trim($phone) !='')
                        $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n"."\n";

                    if(trim($company) !='')
                        $email_message .= "Company Name: ".clean_string($company)."\n"."\n";

                        if(trim($companyweb) !='')
                        $email_message .= "Website URL: ".clean_string($companyweb)."\n"."\n";


                    if(trim($address) !='')
                        $email_message .= "Full Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n"."\n";


                    if(trim($country) !='')
                        $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($country)." (IP Address) : $ipcountry  ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n"."\n";



                    if(trim($brief) !='')
                        $email_message .= "About Myself : ".clean_string($brief)."\n"."\n";

                    $random = mt_rand();
                    $m= new Mail; // create the mail
                    $m->From( $name."<$email>" );
                    $m->To( "abc@gmail.com" );

                    $m->Subject( "Form2 - ".$random );  

                    $m->Body( $email_message);
                    $m->Priority(2) ;

                    if($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]){
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], 'uploadedfiles/'.$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
                        $file_upload = 'uploadedfiles/'.$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
                        $m->Attach( $file_upload) ;
                    }
                    $m->Send();
                header('location:thankyou.php');
                    if($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]){
                        unlink($file_upload);
                    }
                }
            }


            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A captcha image code is usually stored in a session variable. When you display the second form, you are overwriting the captcha from the first form.

Comment: Then sir can u suggest me what to do? actually m not aware of php codes too much pls sir

Comment: Either don't use 2 captchas on the same page or give them different names in the session.

Comment: try with different variable name of captca for both forms

Comment: Actually no I am not getting any error bt what is happening is one form's captcha is working fine bt another one's captcha when I fill right it shows Your captcha is incorrect :(